# How do I display non-discussion posts in a Topic Detail page in Lightning Community Builder?

Tags: lightning, customer-community, community-builder

Right now, by default, the Topic Detail page in Lightning Community Builder is using the "Search Results" Lightning Component:

[image: Topic Detail]

How do I ensure that non-Discussion/question posts appear in the Topic Detail page? I have regular non-question posts that are tagged with topics, but right now only questions appear in the Topic Detail page.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial answer.  I'm trying to figure this out too.  I've created a component that can display related records filtered by topic, but the topic is hard-coded into the component, not filtered dynamically.  Details here:  [How to Filter a Lightning Component based on data elsewhere on the page?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/226965/how-to-filter-a-lightning-component-based-on-data-elsewhere-on-the-page)